# How to use core-js as an external CDN in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, core-js

I know how to specify `externals` in webpack, but it only works when I know the imported variable.

For example, given `import createVuexLogger from "vuex/dist/logger"`, I have to specify `"vuex/dist/logger": "createVuexLogger"`, which `createVuexLogger` is a global variable provided by the cdn js file.

So now I have a problem, I also want to minify my vendor.js by using core-js from CDN. But the problem is, I don't know how is this lib in use. I cannot really find some obvious places which import this file.

Is there any good practice to use core-js as external in webpack?

Comment: Why not using a dynamic import() to specifically split core-js in its own lazy chunk ? From user side, it will have the same effect and you may also gain some benefit from tree shaking. See https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports. Anyway, core-js usually simply extend natives prototypes, simply add your CDN script call and voilà. If using core-js-pure, externals are obvious.

Comment: @Bertrand Thanks for the comment. But actually I'm using `vue-cli`, I don't have full control of how to use `core-js`. Anyway, maybe it is a simple question, but I am new to the frontend world. Really cannot figure out how to use this `core-js`. I tried to use `core-js-bundle`, but cannot find any global variables it exports to the `window`.

Comment: You don't have to care with a global variable unless using a very specific version. core-js automatically shims natives objects. Using import 'core-js' or putting a CDN download script does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Why are you in need of explicitly require core-js ? Vue-cli embeds Babel transpilation that in turn relies on core-js.

Comment: @Bertrand I don't need to explicitly require core-js, but I want to use the core-js from CDN. The problem is I don't know how to tell the webpack to ignore `core-js`, as I will use it from CDN. Your previous comment makes sense, I don't need to do anything else but just add script tag, but the left problem is webpack always trying to bundle the core-js.

Comment: If I understand well, you do not explicitly add an 'import core-js' statement into your code but webpack is still bundling it ? If so, it sounds that's Babel is the culprit. You will have to tweak babel configuration. See https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins. See also https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8590

Comment: @Bertrand Actually that `usebuiltins` really did the trick. I can set it to false to disable auto injecting `core-js`. Thanks a lot :)